# How does Grevious get his first lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, general-grievous

I understand that he takes them as trophies from defeated opponents, but how does he get his first one? Does  he defeat a Jedi without a lightsaber? If so, who? Or is he given one by a Sith? Or does he make his own (without force assistance)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to Wookieepedia, Count Dooku presented him his first lightsaber:

> The cyborg project was funded by San Hill to create a military leader that could counter Dooku's growing political influence in the Separatist Movement, although he presented the finished General Grievous as a twisted gift to Dooku. Though taken aback by his appearance, Dooku was pleased, and bestowed upon Grievous the title "Supreme Commander of the Droid Armies," planning to use him in his efforts to conquer the Republic. He presented him with his first lightsaber, the weapon of Sifo-Dyas, an old friend of Dooku's.

This information comes from 14-page comic *[The Eyes of Revolution](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eyes_of_Revolution)*, from *Star Wars: Visionaries*, in which a fully cybonic "Sheelal", wounded and mind tempered with, receives his first lightsaber from Dooku (reporting to Darth Sidious) and, after reacting with anger and violence at being called a "droid", announces himself to be General Grevious.

[image]

Comment: @DVK, you're right, I dug around a bit more and followed the citations. Is that better? Or is it still missing evidence? (never answered a Star Wars question before!) :-)

Comment: *Helpful* images are encouraged. Ones like this are helpful to illustrate when something happened, or to provide definitive citation. But please don't add images just for the sake of adding images.

Comment: @phantom42 if the image here is helpful and good, why bother making this comment at all?

Comment: @Doc, Richard and I had a conversation through these messages, and have since deleted them (they had nothing to do with the actual question). Phantom42 was responding to that conversation :-)

Comment: Just btw:he weapon that "belonged to an old friend" of Dooku was the light saber of Sifo-Dyas.

Comment: @gruntswilldie, it does say it belonged to Sifo-Dyas in the Wookieepedia quote, but I'll edit it a little to add that it was an old friend into the body of the answer as that is quite symbolic et al. But not being too familiar with the canon myself, are you sure Dooku is being sincere? I mean, were they REALLY "old friends" or was he being sarcastic (such as Voldemort and Harry being 'old friends')?

Comment: They were really close friends - until Dooku decided to murder him of course.

Answer (score -1):

Grevious gained his first Lightsaber after killing a Jedi. The Muk were invading his planet and he became a master with a gun, he met a female of his race, the Kaleesh. When she was killed he changed his name to Grevious from Qymaen Jai Sheelal.

Then the Jedi became involved in this fight and took the side of the Muk, since the Kaleesh had invaded the Muk's home planet. The Jedi forced the Kaleesh back and basically stopped them from leaving their planet. Since Grevious was not on his planet at the time, he hurried back as his planet was being invaded by The Muk again. This time, the Jedi were helping the Kaleesh. Grevious didn't know this and killed the first Jedi He saw. He spotted the Lightsaber and took it.

Comment: Some sources or references would go a long way here. What book(s) or episode(s) did this happen in?