# Whose lightsabers does General Grievous use to fight Kenobi?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, revenge-of-the-sith, general-grievous

I was watching Obi-Wan fight Grievous in this clip and happened to pause right after he cuts off Grievous's second hand as the saber falls away (the 2:36 mark):

Here's a couple screen grabs of what I noticed:

[image: grievous saber 1] [image: grievous saber 2]

What the heck!? That looks identical to Kenobi's saber!

[image: kenobi saber]

Given that Grievous never made his own and had a love for collecting the sabers of Jedi he'd killed, my question is who did the sabers used in this battle originally belong to (especially the Obi-Wan look alike I spotted)?

Comment: This is addressed by [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132279/20774) to the duplicate.

Comment: @Valorum - So the only explanation is the out-of-universe explanation that the hilts were just recycled?

Comment: Yup. And there's no in-universe indication of who the lightsabers belonged to.